# org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a springboot application (jar), i want to deploy it to wildfly (war) i have follow this guide: https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2017/09/02/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-war-in-wildfly-jboss/

Application.java:

```
     package de.fred4jupiter.fredbet;

     import de.fred4jupiter.fredbet.props.CacheNames;
     import de.fred4jupiter.fredbet.props.FredbetProperties;
     import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
     import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
     import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
     import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
     import org.pringframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
     import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
     import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
     import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
     import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
     import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache;
     import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
     import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.cache.ElastiCacheAutoConfiguration;
     import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
     import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
     import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;

     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Properties;

     @SpringBootApplication
     @EnableConfigurationProperties(FredbetProperties.class)
     @EnableCaching
     @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ElastiCacheAutoConfiguration.class)
     public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
        }

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(applicationClass);
        }

        private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

        @Bean
        public Properties buildProperties() throws IOException {
            return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(new ClassPathResource("build.properties"));
        }

        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
            List<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<Cache>();
            caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache(CacheNames.AVAIL_GROUPS));
            caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache(CacheNames.CHILD_RELATION));
            caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache(CacheNames.RUNTIME_CONFIG));
            cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
            return cacheManager;
        }
     }
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.fred4jupiter.fredbet</groupId>
    <artifactId>worldcup2018</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>worldcup2018</name>

    <description>Simple football betting application.</description>

    <contributors>
        <contributor>
            <name>Michael Stähler</name>
        </contributor>
    </contributors>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/fred4jupiter/fredbet.git</developerConnection>
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/fred4jupiter/fredbet.git</connection>
        <url>https://github.com/fred4jupiter/fredbet</url>
    </scm>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <buildtimestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildtimestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
```

Application.app

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graylog2.log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j2-gelf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- webjars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fluentlenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluentlenium-assertj</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>archunit-junit</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>worldcup2018</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/build.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/build.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <executions> -->
                <!-- <execution> -->
                <!-- <goals> -->
                <!-- <goal>repackage</goal> -->
                <!-- </goals> -->
                <!-- </execution> -->
                <!-- </executions> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*UT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- Manual tests will be excluded -->
                                <exclude>**/*MT.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- Manual tests will be excluded -->
                                <exclude>**/*MT.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>acceptance</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*AT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*UT.java</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
                                <!-- Manual tests will be excluded -->
                                <exclude>**/*MT.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

When i do a mvn package i have this error:

/src/main/java/de/fred4jupiter/fredbet/Application.java:[39,8] cannot access org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer
[ERROR]   class file for org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer not found

Do you have any idea?

Thanks,

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix typo:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.fred4jupiter.fredbet</groupId>
    <artifactId>fredbet</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Fredbet</name>

    <description>Simple football betting application.</description>

    <contributors>
        <contributor>
            <name>Michael Stähler</name>
        </contributor>
    </contributors>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/fred4jupiter/fredbet.git</developerConnection>
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/fred4jupiter/fredbet.git</connection>
        <url>https://github.com/fred4jupiter/fredbet</url>
    </scm>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <buildtimestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildtimestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graylog2.log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j2-gelf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- webjars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fluentlenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluentlenium-assertj</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>archunit-junit</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>fredbet</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/build.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/build.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <executions> -->
                <!-- <execution> -->
                <!-- <goals> -->
                <!-- <goal>repackage</goal> -->
                <!-- </goals> -->
                <!-- </execution> -->
                <!-- </executions> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*UT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- Manual tests will be excluded -->
                                <exclude>**/*MT.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- Manual tests will be excluded -->
                                <exclude>**/*MT.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>acceptance</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*AT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*UT.java</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
                                <!-- Manual tests will be excluded -->
                                <exclude>**/*MT.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

code:

```
package de.fred4jupiter.fredbet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.cache.ElastiCacheAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;

import de.fred4jupiter.fredbet.props.CacheNames;
import de.fred4jupiter.fredbet.props.FredbetProperties;

/**
 * Main application start.
 * 
 * NOTE: To disable thymeleaf caching correctly please activate the dev profile
 * on local development.
 * 
 * @author michael
 *
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FredbetProperties.class)
@EnableCaching
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ElastiCacheAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.addInitializers(new AppInitializer());
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties buildProperties() throws IOException {
        return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(new ClassPathResource("build.properties"));
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        List<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<Cache>();
        caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache(CacheNames.AVAIL_GROUPS));
        caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache(CacheNames.CHILD_RELATION));
        caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache(CacheNames.RUNTIME_CONFIG));
        cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), consider adding some explanations and make clear where exactly you fixed a tyop and why it didn't fit in the comments.